# "Duplicate identifier" error when converting project to Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm currently trying to convert an existing JavaScript application to TypeScript. To be able to do this step by step, I started by compiling the existing JavaScript code using the compiler option "allowJs". When I start converting existing files to TypeScript, I get errors with creating the namespaces.

So, a basic example. I have these two files, a new TypeScript file:

```
namespace myapp {
    export var c1 = 5;
}
```

And an old JavaScript file:

```
var myapp = myapp || {};
myapp.c2 = 4;
```

This leads to a valid JavaScript output, but there will be an error:

```
error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'myapp'.
```

Is there any way to avoid getting this error or any other way to convert files which all use the same namespace?

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think a better approach could be to transpile your .ts files with typescript and then create your application with all generated and implemented files using a tool like webpack

Comment: Bundling should not be an issue currently, or rather an issue for a later time. Right now, we just include all script files individually, but that's definitely something to look into afterwards. But right now, it's more of a compile time issue.

Answer (score 0):

in your `tsconfig.json` provide either "files" or "exclude" field to include or exclude files respectively.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "files" : ["/path/to/ts/file.ts", ...]

}
```

OR

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "exclude" : ["node_modules", "/path/to/build/js/"]

}
```

The reason to this problem is that typescript compiler knows about both original (typescript) source files and the transpiled (javascript) files, hence getting the same reference twice. Now your job is to either include only source typescript files or to exclude all non typescript files.

Comment: Ideally, I want to be able to compile both old JS and new TS files while converting, but this could be a solution until everything is converted.

Comment: If you want to allow both js and ts try to exclude those js files which are auto generated from ts files.

Comment: Those should not be an issue, it seemed like TypeScript ignores them anyway. It's really just the problem that TypeScript is a bit too strict with duplicate definitions that span JavaScript AND TypeScript files.
Because TypeScript will generate something like

var myapp;
...
var myapp;

as well.